# Vector graphics + matplotlib pcolorfast

Tags: python, matplotlib, vector-graphics

To keep it short: Is there a way to export plots created with methods like
[pcolorfast](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html) which basically draw pixels as "real" vector graphics?

I tried to do just that using [savefig](http://matplotlib.org/api/figure_api.html) and saving to a PDF but what would happen is that the plot was actually a vector graphic but the parts drawn by pcolorfast(so basically, what is inside the axes) something like a bitmap. - I checked this using Inkscape.

This resulted in really low resolution plots even though the arrays drawn with pcolorfast where about 3000x4000. I achieved higher resolution by increasing the dpi when exporting, but I'd really appreciate a conversion to a real vector graphic.

**Edit:** I updated my original code by the piece of code below that should serve to illustrate what exactly I am doing. I tried to involucrate the rasterized tip, but it has had no effect. I still end up with a supersmall PDF-file where the plots are acually raster images (png). I am going to provide you with the data I used and the resulting PDF.

http://www.megafileupload.com/k5ku/test_array1.txt

http://www.megafileupload.com/k5kv/test_array2.txt

http://www.megafileupload.com/k5kw/test.pdf

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

arr1= np.loadtxt("test_array1.txt")
arr2= np.loadtxt("test_array2.txt")

fig, (ax1, ax2)=plt.subplots(1, 2)
ax1.set_rasterized(False)
ax1.pcolorfast(arr1)

ax2.pcolorfast(arr2, rasterized=False)

plt.show()

fig.set_rasterized(False)
fig.savefig("test.pdf")
```

Comment: You tried output.svg? I also think, that a dpi-setting should not have any effect when outputting some vector-graphic. I don't know how output.pdf behaves. (Also: i never had problems with bad resolution in pdf output; is this also visible within a good pdf-reader?)

Comment: try doing `.set_rasterizef(False)` on the artist.  Also check that it is above the z threshold where mpl automatically rasterizes.  Be aware that 'real vectors' for a 3kx4k array is going to have a >10x blow up in size.

Comment: @tcaswell Pls, see my edit and tell me if that is what you suggested and let me know what it is that I am doing wrong

Comment: @sascha I would really like to output PDFs and i think I tried SVG beforehand but it didn't have any effect. If you want to try my case then pls see my edit for code and test data.